# Laravel - Inserting Related Models

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a system in Laravel 6. The system inserts a row into a header table and in the same operation needs to insert related details into a detail table. Is there a better way of doing this than the below:

````
$header = new RequestHeader;
$insert = $header->create($data)->id;

$meta = RequestHeader::find($insert);
$meta->details()->createMany($data['module']);
$meta->status()->create(['status' => $initialStatus, 'action_by' => \Auth::user()->username]);```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below because, you have modal object so, no need to apply query to find it out.

```
$header = new RequestHeader;
$meta = $header->create($data);

$meta->details()->createMany($data['module']);
$meta->status()->create(['status' => $initialStatus, 'action_by' => \Auth::user()->username]);
```